# Inserting timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to insert the row below into Oracle database, but I get error
`[22008][1830] ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

```
insert into tbl (coldate, start, end) 
values (
TO_DATE('2005-03-04 02:04:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-23 09:06:51.055000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-04-26 23:32:59.430000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what you should do: your format mask is too "short" for the value you provide. You need to include the fractional seconds in the format mask for `to_timestamp()`

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-23 09:06:51.055000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
```

For more details on the format model used in `to_timestamp()` please see the manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fractional second specification in your format string:

```
insert into tbl (coldate, start, end) 
values (
TO_DATE('2005-03-04 02:04:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-03-23 09:06:51.055000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 
-- Here ----------------------------------------------------------^
TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-04-26 23:32:59.430000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
-- And here ------------------------------------------------------^
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this using the seemingly undocumented function `TIMESTAMP`

TIMESTAMP does not require date format to be passed, however the date needs to be in standard UTC date format.

For example:

```
insert into table (dateTimeField) values (TIMESTAMP '2019-07-24 04:23:14');
```